# Do Olimar's Pikmin increase his weight?

Tags: super-smash-bros-brawl

Do the pikmin that follow olimar in ssbb add weight to his character, and if so does the weight build and translate into smash damage? I'm wondering because I've noticed that my smashes in the home-run-contest are a bit stronger when I have more Pikmin.

[image: =]

[image]

Comment: Do note purple pikmin (which you get in the home run derby) hit the hardest in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Super Smash Bros Wiki, Olimar's damage is stacked up by the different colors of Pikmin. Each color of Pikmin has it's own variety of skill sets and advantages. The purple Pikmin is the only color of Pikmin Olimar will pull for the Home Run Derby which would explain the difference in power compared to a normal match-up where Olimar would pull more than just purple Pikmin.

[My resource of information](http://super-smash-bros.wikia.com/wiki/Olimar_(SSBB))

Edit: To further answer the question. Olimar's physical weight/gravity is not affected by Pikmin however, the weight in damage is reflected through the variety of traits that Pikmin have depending on their color.

The number of Pikmin do not affect the Home Run derby due to the Purple being on the stage and will always be last in line.

The number of Pikmin do affect the normal battle because of variety of colors that are available and each color of Pikmin having different traits.

Comment: This doesn't seem to actually be answering the question asked, which was whether the pikmin add to he weight, and/or whether having more pikmin adds to his damage.

Comment: Well in fact the resource link does answer that Pikmin add to the damage rather than weight be a reflection of damage between the two different scenarios described.

Comment: All you really said was that purples hit harder. The question was asking about the amount of pikmin within home run mode.

Comment: Well then the answer would be presumed as the amount of Pikmin shouldn't matter as long as the purple Pikmin is the last in line (which obviously in a case where all Pikmin are purple it doesn't matter) then having the purple Pikmin alone in the Home Run Smash is going to be more beneficial to that event then compared to having a purple Pikmin in a normal battle that is not last in line. Therefore, the number of Pikmin on stage for the Home Run Smash does not matter compared to the number of Pikmin in battle will be more beneficial and that having the purple Pikmin will cause more damage.

Comment: Well then, if having more pikmin won't increase Olimar's weight nor damage, that is the answer to the question, and *you should have said so in your answer*. It very much should not 'be presumed', because it's the exact thing that was asked.

Comment: As far as weight; I don't think that the weight in question is physical weight as Olimar's gravity is never affected by Pikmin when jumping. However, the weight of damage can be implied by the question as Pikmin increase the damage depending on color and traits; so the answer is 'yes' Pikmin increase the weight in damage, but 'no' not Olimar's physical weight or gravity.

Answer (score 3):

There is no evidence that current Pikmin affect Olimar's physical properties (including weight) in any way. They simply affect the damage, power, size, and other characteristics of the hitboxes of his smashes, directional aerials, specials, and throws.

If you're seeing a difference in the distance of your Home-Run Bat swing at equal damages, that isn't due to your Pikmin; it's probably just due to how the Home-Run Bat's forward smash has four different hitboxes of varying knockback and you haven't yet mastered controlling which one you're hitting with.